Is this system truly superior to french drain?
I recently watched a few videos by this company, who purports that their system works better than French drains.  The rationale is that the water that seeps in is lower than the French drain; their system relies on a perforated pipe placed below the level of the cold joint between the footing and the wall.  They say theirs is better and the only way to deal with water accumulating where it doesn't belong.
Source
My question, simply enough, is ... are they right?  We have exactly the problem described in the video as nearly as we can tell.  Grateful for any guidance as I know little about basements and don't know who is trustworthy!

Basically that is how it should be done to remove water from underneath the floor.  Second part is to seal the concrete walls from outside.

The best way is a foundation drain at the level of the footer outside the building. Easily put in at construction time, not so easy to retrofit. But if you're going to seal the outside of the foundation, might as well keep digging and put the pipe in out there, too. As far as I'm concerned a French drain is a ditch with a pipe at the bottom and drainage material above it - those can be helpful at intercepting and removing water before it gets into your basement, but they don't go in your basement.

But that system includes a french drain...  The only benefit I see is low head for the drain board.
